# finding undefined symbol

Tags: dynamic-linking

I am trying to run  a program whose source I downloaded and compiled. When I try to run the program I keep getting the message:

```
unable to load undefined symbol _z15InvalidateImageSs
```

I am trying to determine why I am getting this error.
The program is actually a library that is loaded by another program. My program compiles to a .so file.

I ran:

```
$ nm myprog.so > nm.txt
```

the symbol shows up in the file, but has no address associated with it.

1. I searched the source tree for the symbol using:

`$ find . -type f | xargs fgrep -I '_zinvalidateimagess' | grep -v 'Binary`

I got no results.
2. I searched all standard load libraries for the symbol:

```
$ scanelf -l -s _zInvalidateImageSs | grep -I '_zinvalidateImageSs'
```

no results again.

So my question is:
If the symbol is never referenced anywhere in the source tree, why is it a problem in the .so file?
How do I figure out where this symbol is supposed to be coming from?

Comment: Search for `InvalidateImage` .The other characters are due to C++ name mangling.

Comment: What does `ldd program` show? Paste the results into your question, please.

Answer (score 2):

The source for the library can *declare* a symbol without *defining* it, by doing something like this

```
extern InvalidateImage(const char *);
```

and later using it

```
const char *foo = InvalidateImage(bar);
```

Because it is a library, you would not notice this until you attempt to run the program which uses this symbol.  The place to *look* for the symbol is where you downloaded the library's source: likely the developer of that library provides either the related source directly or some clues regarding where they get it from.

For what it's worth, I use scripts ([`exports`](http://invisible-island.net/scripts/readme.html#item:exports) and [`externs`](http://invisible-island.net/scripts/readme.html#item:externs)) to check for missing symbols in the programs which I maintain.

Further reading:

- [Unresolved external symbol in object files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9928238/unresolved-external-symbol-in-object-files)
- [What is the difference between a definition and a declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410563/what-is-the-difference-between-a-definition-and-a-declaration)